# How to set up 2 IBDatabase to 1 IBTransaction?

Tags: delphi, transactions, database-connection

I have one IBDatabase in DataModule linked with my IBTransaction.
In one module of project I need to control the persistence in two database.

For this, I am adding the second IBDatabase this way:

```pascal
constructor TConnections.Create(AIBDatabase: TIBDatabase);
begin
  if AIBDatabase = nil then
    raise Exception.Create('The base connection is needed!');
  inherited Create;
  FIBDatabase := TIBDatabase.Create(nil);
  FIBDatabase.LoginPrompt := false;
  FIBDatabase.Params.Clear;
  FIBDatabase.Params.Text := AIBDatabase.Params.Text;
  FIBDatabase.DatabaseName := AIBDatabase.DatabaseName.Replace('DB.GDB', 'DB2.GDB');
end;

procedure TConnections.SetTransaction(AIBTransaction: TIBTransaction);
begin
  if AIBTransaction = nil then
    raise Exception.Create('Then Transaction is needed!');
  AIBTransaction.AddDatabase(FIBDatabase);
  FIBDatabase.DefaultTransaction := AIBTransaction;
  FIBDatabase.Open;
end;
```

Any select commands are work fine, but in insert command the error occurs.
Well, I have this:

```pascal
connections := TConnections.Create(Dm.Database);
try
  connection.SetTransaction(Dm.Transaction);

  qry := TIBQuery.Create(nil);
  qry.Database := Dm.Database;
  try
    // here are commands with Dm.Transaction
    // ...
    qry.ExecSql;
  finally
    qry.Free;
  end;

  otherQry := TIBQuery.Create(nil);
  otherQry.Database := connection.OtherDatabase;
  try
    // here are commands with connection.OtherDatabase but same Transaction
    // ...
    otherQry.ExecSql;  // The error occurs here.
  finally
    otherQry.Free;
  end;

  Dm.Transaction.Commit;
finally
  connection.Free;
end;
```

> 'invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)'

These block is envolved in `try except`.
So, if I try again, after the error, the process runs smoothly.

**What's wrong in my configuration?**

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use the same transaction with two separate databases. The transaction acts on the tables within the database.

Comment: @KenWhite, the error only occurs on the first try. After the first time, the rollback and commit work fine for both databases. Thanks.

Comment: This may occur if you started transaction explicitly. Every explicit  transactions must be finished explicitly. So, if your connection is open explicitly, you should close it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may occur if you started transaction explicitly. Every explicit transactions must be finished explicitly. So, if your connection is open explicitly, you should close it explicitly.

You may use :

```
//Commit(Stop) the transaction before open an other connection
if Dm.Transaction.InTransaction then 
  dm.Transaction.Commit;
```

> Note: In applications that connect an InterBaseExpress dataset to a client dataset, every query must be in its own transaction. You must use one transaction component for each query component.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/IBX.IBDatabase.TIBTransaction

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your proposal. I do not want perform the **commit** before performing the processes in the other **Database** because I want to track changes in both databases.

Comment: I ran the `Commit` before `connections: = TConnections.Create (Dm.Database);` and then it worked. Somewhere, perhaps a simple `select` a **transaction** is getting open.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that it was a "Two Phase commit". I will correct my answer. You are right about `select`.